# Cron jobs do not execute

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, cron, python3

I have 3 python scripts which are scheduled in the same crontab as :

```
# Script 1
0 0,6,12,18 * * * cd path/to/script && /usr/bin/python3.8 -W ignore script1.py >> file1.out
# Script 2
0 0,6,12,18 * * * cd path/to/script && /usr/bin/python3.8 -W ignore script2.py >> file2.out
# Script 3
0 0,6,12,18 * * * cd path/to/script && /usr/bin/python3.8 -W ignore script3.py >> file3.out
```

The scripts are deployed on an EC2 (Ubuntu, t2.micro), in which I have checked CloudWatch and saw no spike in CPU Usage. What I have seen though is a big spike on Network In and Network Packets In - all scripts are fetching data from APIs, thus the spike I suppose.

Cron sequence does not seem to matter, as on another instance with 4 deployed scripts, 2/4 cron jobs fail in no-sequencial order (1 and 4 fails).

My only thought was that the scripts did not execute due to a network limit for this type of instance, which indeed is the case but doesn't explain that the scripts do not execute at all.

What am I missing?

**Update**

For script 3 there is an error in system logs "MTA not installed - discarding output"

Comment: `MTA not installed - discarding output`. This means that at least one script issues errors and cron tries to send this error text via email, which does not work because no mail server (MTA: mail transfer agent) is available. Append `2>>&1` to your jobs to see stderr in logfiles.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing?

Error handling?

I would redirect errors to a file

```
0 0,6,12,18 * * * cd path/to/script && /usr/bin/python3.8 -W ignore script1.py >> file1.out 2> script1.err
```